# bootstrap accordion icon change in click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap accordion in my code. On click on every list I will display Data and Icon will change.

```
<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
```

will change to

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
```

My code:-

```
<div class="priority-lists">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#waterMindDistrictMeteres">
                 <h2 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">
                                                <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
                                                WaterMind District Meters
                                            </h2>

            </div>
            <div id="waterMindDistrictMeteres" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="servicePointsGrid" watermind-priority-lists kendo-grid k-options="watermindDetailGridOptions" k-rebind="watermindDetailGridOptions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#waterMindPressurePoints">
                 <h2 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">
                                                <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
                                                WaterMind Pressure Points
                                            </h2>

            </div>
            <div id="waterMindPressurePoints" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="servicePointsGrid" watermind-priority-lists kendo-grid k-options="watermindDetailGridOptions" k-rebind="watermindDetailGridOptions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#waterMindServicePoints">
                 <h2 class="panel-title accordion-toggle">
                                                <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
                                                WaterMind Service Points
                                            </h2>

            </div>
            <div id="waterMindServicePoints" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="servicePointsGrid" watermind-priority-lists kendo-grid k-options="watermindDetailGridOptions" k-rebind="watermindDetailGridOptions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use some code:

[My jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/7FqsX/100/)

I will see icon are not working properly. I am looking for solution in CSS or JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: "not working properly" It seems to be working fine in Chrome 38.

Comment: Working just fine in firefox 32 :)

Comment: No, I see an error here, they all launch as minus's and when you click on it turns into the propper icon it should be.

Comment: yes true @Dorvalla that is what problem I am facing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `.collapsed` to your panel-headings! The first time `.collapsed` is not on that element, but bootstrap updated it on a click.

It does work fine by me now.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4owgc0q/)

Comment: Andreas is right, you have to add `.collapsed` !
`class="panel-heading collapsed"`

Answer (score 4):

```
Please check on this link
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FqsX/102/)

```
You must add a class "collapsed" next to "panel-heading". your problem will be solved
```

Answer (score 3):

You should init your icons with : `fa-plus-square`, not `fa-minus-square`.

Comment: can u please refer my jsfiddle.. I see an error here, they all launch as minus's and when you click on it turns into the propper icon it should be